# Regex for multiple Consonants

Tags: php, regex, string, logic

I am looking for a regex pattern I want to use in my php name generator script.

It should detect if the string contains three consecutive consonants.
But it should not detect the string if two consecutive consonants of the three consecutive consonants are the same.

Example:

```
"hello" -> False, because there aren't 3 consecutive consonants.
"matching" -> True, because there are 3 consecutive consonants.
"apple" -> False, although there are 3 consecutive consonants, because two consecutive of them are the same.
```

Please help me to find such a regex pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])(?!\2)){3}`

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2vtnt

---

**Edit**

There's an edge case with this pattern that it fails if it's proceeded by the same last consonant.
E.g `xyzz` should match `xyz` but doesn't.

This would be a more accurate pattern.
`(([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])(?!\2)){2}[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`

Comment: @ugoren xyxx doesn't contain 3 consecutive consonants

Comment: OK, you treat `y` as a vowel. `bdbb` then.

Comment: You're right, there's an edge case in the pattern where the match fails if its followed by the same consonant.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a negative assertion and a lookback:
1. Use the lookback to build an expression to match two identical characters: `(.)\1`.
2. Add `.?`, before it, to catch the pair either immediately or after a character: `.?(.)\1`.
3. 3 consecutive consonants: `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{3}`
4. Add #2 above as a negative assertion: `(?!.?(.)\1)[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{3}`.

I took some parts from @zapthedingbat's answer, which is more elagant, but (I think) errs a bit.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I am not fit enough with regex to write the result, too.

Comment: Looking at @zapthedingbat's answer, I figured out the syntax and completed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
/([^aeiou]{3})/i
```

`^` in the class means it should NOT comtain a,e,i,o,u

Comment: Unfortunately it will capture [non-alphabetic characters](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ePCAYe) too.

Answer (score 0):

```
/([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{3})/i
```

This will match 3 consonants in a row. And then `str_split` the match and check whether all three items are different.

```
preg_match_all('/([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{3})/i', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $items = str_split(strtolower($match));
    if ($items[0] != $items[1] && $items[1] != $items[2]) {
        // match
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works halfway. It doesn't consider that the two consonants have to be consecutive. For example `apgpel` matches but it shouldn't because the two `p` don't meet.